# How often will $a_{n+1}=|a_n|^p\sin a_n$ tend to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Consider sequence $a_1=x$, $a_{n+1}=|a_n|^p\sin a_n$. Denote $S$ the set $\Big\{x\ \Big\vert \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\Big\}$, whats the value of $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{2x}\mu([-x,x]\cap S)?$$
>   (where $\mu(M)$ denotes the measure of $M$)

I tried starting with $p=2$. I plotted the graph of $\ln |a_n|$ with many $x$. It seems that almost every $x$ will make the limit tends to $0$.
For $0\le p< 1$, I can prove that the limit is $1$. All of the $x$ will make $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ tend to $0$.
Also, I can calculate that for $p=1$ the limit we want to find is also $1$.

Comment: Do you require $p>0$ ?

Comment: No. When $p<-1$ the limit I want to find can be easily found as $0$.

Comment: When $p>1$, $a_n \to 0$ iff $|a_n| < 1$ for some $n$. Therefore, it suffices to show $\cup_{n \ge 0} f^{-n}(E)$ has full measure, where $f(x) = x^2\sin(x)$ and $E = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2|\sin(x)| > 1\}$. Note that $E$ looks like $\cup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} [2\pi k - \epsilon_k, 2\pi k+\epsilon_k]$ for $\epsilon_k \sim \frac{1}{4\pi^2 k^2}$.